# Most efficient way to redirect several TLD's sharing a common root to one primary domain using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, tld

I'm using the following code (repeated) to redirect 6 additional TLDs to one primary TLD. is there a more efficient way to achieve the same result?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .?$ http://www.mydomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: No, although I would also redirect the none www version to the www version (or the other way around) so you don't have content duplication. Also you could replace `.?$` by `^` and save 2 bytes. (What did you mean with `repeated` by the way?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.org$1 [R=301,L]
```

This redirects any domain which is not .org to .org

Comment: this works great but you have to add a slash `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.org/$1 [R=301,L]` after the org or it messes up folders and files. i.e. it will come out `http://www.domain.orgindex.htm`

Comment: also... it redirects any domain which is not `domain.org` to `domain.org` it is not just for the org part, correct?

Answer (score 0):

If there are a lot of domains, you may want to look at [RewriteMap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) which will allow you to create external maps, but this would need to be in your server/vhost config, won't work in an .htaccess file. Other than that, this is the usual way to do this.